# Fail to get Responsecode from HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, url, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to get the response code from a URL:

```
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL" );
    Utils.noCerts(sslContext);
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    URL url = new URL("https://abc.def.efg:1234/hij/klm.svc/nop");
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);

    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
```

I have tried this with multiple URLs in my network.  For some, it works fine.  It tells me the response code perfectly.  However with other links it gives me a 401 (even though I can access it via Chrome) and gives me the following error:

```
2013-12-09 09:21:40.590 java[32438:1203] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
```

I thought it may be an authentication issue.  So after creating 'urlConnection' I added the following code as well:

```
    String userPassword = "user:password";  //hardcoded for now
    String encoding = new BASE64Encoder().encode((userPassword).getBytes());
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + encoding);
```

However that still gave me a 401 and gave me the same error message as above.

Any ideas or information on what could be causing this issue would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add space after "Basic "

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Can you just explain a bit more on why?  Thanks

Comment: I added link and basic explanation in answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look how should look [Basic Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) header. You create it without the space so server can't validate it.

Without space it will look like this:

```
Authorization: BasicQWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```